# How to disable widget's generic CSS style?

Tags: gwt

Seems trivial but I can't find the answer anywhere. I'd like to get rid of eg. "gwt-PopupPanel" style which is added for each popup. Is there a way to do it in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PopupPanel panel = new PopupPanel();
panel.setStylePrimaryName("mypopup");
```

All popup style will now use mypopup instead of gwt-PopupPanel.

Comment: yes. Or you can do `panel.removeStyleName("gwt-PopupPanel");` to get rid of it.